# In C ensure that the number of assembly instructions is fixed for multiple sections of code

Tags: c, assembly, goto, dispatch, vm-implementation

In a virtual machine I'm writing, I want to be able to dispatch commands in a manner similar to the following pseudo code.

```
add: reg[memory[pc+1]] =  reg[memory[pc+1]] + reg[memory[pc+2]]; pc += 2; goto done;
sub: reg[memory[pc+1]] =  reg[memory[pc+1]] - reg[memory[pc+2]]; pc += 2; goto done;
cmp: /* Would take more space than simply x = x + y; */ goto done;

for(int pc = 0; memory[pc] != END; pc++) {
    goto currentPositionInMemorySomehow + (memory[pc] * lengthOfInstruction);
    done:
}
```

Where memory is an array containing the bytecode, and pc a program counter. To do this however requires that each of these positions we jump to has the exact same number of instructions before the next block. Dropping down to assembly is not an option, unless there is a wonderful platform agnostic assembly code, which allows for one to take the same code and compile to Linux, Mac, and Windows. Regardless of the processor each is sitting on top of. Any and all help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I assume the second instruction is supposed to be called `sub`, and not `add`? FWIW, why must each instruction be the same length? Is the C code inlined? Why not use a jump table instead? The opcode+operands size can be the same size, each time. Even if opcode+operand are not the same size, the code for the opcode can move the instruction pointer (pc) instead. The opcode knows the size of its operands. -- That is how I would do this.

Comment: Btw, C doesn't have computed `goto`, if it works at all it's only as an extension. Why not use a `switch` statement? The compiler-generated jump table (assuming that's what you get) introduces an extra indirection, where you want a multiplication, but are you sure that's costing you?

Comment: @SteveJessop: Compiler may even use a direct computed jump in some cases, so there might not even be any extra indirection

Comment: @Hasturkun: true, the compiler has a shot at making all the cases the same size, by inserting nops or whatever to pad the small ones. Do any compilers actually do it?

Comment: @Rudy I've updated the question so that the second add is now a sub. Thanks for catching that.
@All I was under the impression that a switch statement was rather like a condensed set of if statements. However, I shall have to look into that. I attempted to use a jump table before, but I ran into a whole truckload of problems regarding it not wanting me to store labels in an array.

Comment: @Steve: I've seen gcc do it for some dense (ie. not sparse) switches, but that's more or less anecdotal

Comment: @Maatthew: That's because you can't get the address of a label in standard C, some compiler extensions may allow this.

Comment: @Mathew: But you can get the address of functions. The functions can also update the (global) program counter pc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I don't know of a way to achieve exactly what you want (and the only compiler I know that allows computed jumps is gcc), I suggest you simply use a `switch`, which most decent optimizing compilers will transform into either a jump table, or a computed jump, handling instruction alignment correctly in a way appropriate for your platform.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to want to write some C code that will compile to executable code of size that is independent of target platform. That is quite simply an unrealistic goal.

Comment: I was not saying that the size of the executable had to be constant across platforms, but merely that the size of each instruction branch had to be constant across the executable for one platform. However I wasn't aware that the C compiler was clever enough to optimize switch statements. So I will simply use one of those for now, and add a JIT later to make up for that performance cost.